# Vector maximizing $L_1$ norm when hit by Hadamard matrix?

Tags: normed-spaces, hadamard-matrices

Given the Hadamard matrix $H_k \in \{ \pm 1\}^{2^k}$ constructed recursively as $\begin{bmatrix} H_{k-1} & H_{k-1} \\ H_{k-1} & - H_{k-1} \end{bmatrix}$ with $H_0 = [1]$, find a vector in $\{ -1,0,1 \}^{2^k}$ which maximizes $\| H_k v\|_1$? I am also interested in the value achieved by the maximizer itself.

A naive upper bound shows that $\| H_k v \|_1 \le \sqrt{2^k} \| H_k v \|_2 = 2^k \| v \|_2 \le (2^k)^{3/2}$. I wonder if it is achievable given the integrality constraint on the vector $v$.

Comment: @MartinR Good catch. $H_0 = [1]$ (I have edited the question to reflect this). The answer does not depend on this though, since I say $H_0 \in \{ \pm 1 \}^1$ (and the sign is irrelevant for the question).

Comment: Did you try to find the maximizer for small values of $k$, e.g. with a computer program? That might give some ideas about the general solution.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for the suggestion! I ran some simulations. Here are two interesting observations:

(1) I computed the maximizer until dimension 8. It turns out to take value $20$ (for $k=3$ and $8$ for $k=2$). The (not unique) maximizer is all $+1's$, except the last co-ordinate is $-1$.

(2) I computed $\| H v \|_1$ for $v$ being the above vector. As $k$ grows, it seems that $\| H v \|_1$ for this vector is upper bounded by $3 (2^k)$ (and approaches this value for larger $k$). This is better than the naive upper bound by a factor of $\sqrt{2^k}$.

Comment: @MartinR For larger $k$ it turns out that the vector which has $\frac{3}{4} \times 2^k$, $+1$'s followed by $\frac{1}{4} \times 2^k$, $-1$'s achieves a larger value approaching $4 (2^k)$.

Comment: when k=5, take x = [-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.,  1., 1.,  1.,  1., 
 -1.,  1., -1.,  1., -1.,  1., -1.,  1., -1.,  1., -1.,  1.,  1., -1., 1.,  1.],  $\|\frac{1}{32}H_{5}x\|_1=4.75$. It should be $O(2^k poly(k))$, but I found it hard to prove this conjecture.